# $watch API description - first function described as listener function, why?

Tags: angularjs

I'm reading through documentation on scope's method `$watch` [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch). The method accepts:
`$watch(watchExpression, [listener]`;
Then they provide examples:

```
// let's assume that scope was dependency injected as the $rootScope
var scope = $rootScope;
scope.name = 'misko';
scope.counter = 0;

expect(scope.counter).toEqual(0);
scope.$watch('name', function(newValue, oldValue) {
 scope.counter = scope.counter + 1;
});
expect(scope.counter).toEqual(0);

scope.$digest();
// the listener is always called during the first $digest loop after it was registered
expect(scope.counter).toEqual(1);

scope.$digest();
// but now it will not be called unless the value changes
expect(scope.counter).toEqual(1);

scope.name = 'adam';
scope.$digest();
expect(scope.counter).toEqual(2);



// Using a listener function
var food;
scope.foodCounter = 0;
expect(scope.foodCounter).toEqual(0);
scope.$watch(
 // This is the listener function --------- WHY ?????????????
 function() { return food; },
 // This is the change handler ---- THIS SHOULD BE A LISTNER FUNCTION
 function(newValue, oldValue) {
   if ( newValue !== oldValue ) {
     // Only increment the counter if the value changed
     scope.foodCounter = scope.foodCounter + 1;
   }
 }
);
// No digest has been run so the counter will be zero
expect(scope.foodCounter).toEqual(0);

// Run the digest but since food has not changed count will still be zero
scope.$digest();
expect(scope.foodCounter).toEqual(0);

// Update food and run digest.  Now the counter will increment
food = 'cheeseburger';
scope.$digest();
expect(scope.foodCounter).toEqual(1);
```

What I don't understand is that why they refer to `function() { return food; }` in the second example as a `// This is the listener function` if this is the function that `should return the value that will be watched.` which is a `watchExpression`?

Comment: it's basically the same thing, only you have more control over it. Instead of the watch looking at a value on a scope, it will execute the function and look at it's return value and compare it to the original value. When it changes, the callback is executed. it should return a value to be compared.

Comment: One use of it, as you can see from the example, is to watch something that can't be referenced using a watchExpression such as the local `food` var.

Comment: Another might be watching for when a particular number becomes larger or smaller than x.

Comment: @KevinB, thanks! So the values that the function returns are compared and not the properties on scope?

Comment: Yes, when you pass a function. Of course, you could return something from the scope too, though it wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: Thanks! But I still don't understand why they called the function listner if it returns the value for camparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment is a little bit misleading and you might file an issue or pull request to improve it.

As you said correctly there are 2 arguments for `$watch(watchExpression, [listener])`

- `watchExpression`
  The watchExpression is called on every call to $digest() and should return the value that will be watched.
  The watch expression can be either a `string` or a `function`.
  If you specify a function this is **not** the listener but rather a comparison function which will be called many many times so don't do any fancy stuff here ;)
  This comparison function is used for the angular dirty checking.
  More details on this can be found in this part of the video by the creator of angularJs: https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=ZhfUv0spHCY#t=1988
- `listener`
  This function is called whenever the value of your `watchExpression` changes.
  So this a perfect place to update your models and do your fancy business logic